# How to send and receive arguments between views in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, routes

I'm trying to send data from a page to another in `flutter` project, tried all methods I found in another question but all failed, here is my code :

The first page :

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/line_details', arguments: {'line':line,});
```

The second page:

```dart
class _LineDetailsState extends State<LineDetails> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data  = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("$data"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**note**: the `line` is a custom object created.

**the error** : always returns null, even when tried to send a single string as `{"test": "test string"}` it returns a null too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Example is working fine

route in MaterialApp

```
routes: { "/line_details": (context) => LineDetails(), },
```

Push on FlatButton:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/line_details', arguments: {'line':'test',}),
```

class LineDetails

```
class LineDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LineDetailsState createState() => _LineDetailsState();
}

class _LineDetailsState extends State<LineDetails> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data  = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    print(data);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("$data"),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

with GestureDetector is also working

```
new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/line_details', arguments: {'line':'test',}),
            child: new Container(child: new Text("GestureDetector"),),
          ),
```

Comment: I am using `GestureDetector` and using `onTap() {}` instead of a button , this may affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    LineDetailsState(
        builder: (context) => LineDetailsState(
              line: line
            )))
```

and

```
class LineDetailsState extends StatefulWidget {
  LineDetailsState(this.line);

  Line line;

  @override
  _LineDetailsState createState() => _LineDetailsState();
}

class _LineDetailsState extends State<LineDetails> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data  = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("$data"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

instead of "Line" replace it with name of your custom object

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks proper one other thing you can try is typecast your argument
like below which help dart for linting. Note this is not related that you are getting null

```
    class LineDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LineDetailsState createState() => _LineDetailsState();
}

class _LineDetailsState extends State<LineDetails> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data  = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String,object>;

    print(data);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text("$data"),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```